# JQuery slideUp/Down loop?

Tags: jquery, loops, html, slidedown, slideup

Where am I wrong?
http://jsfiddle.net/j5yTU/

Just want the .ex to slide up when the mouse is leaving the area.. but it seems to loop and then slide up.

```
 $("div.case").mouseover(function () {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
$(this).css("opacity", "1").css("filter", "alpha(opacity=100)");
$(".ex"+id).slideDown(500);
});

$("div.case").mouseout(function () {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
$(this).css("opacity", "0.4").css("filter", "alpha(opacity=40)");
$(".ex"+id).slideUp(500);
});
```

Anyone knowing what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a better way for you to do this function:

```
$('.case').hover(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).css('opacity':'1','filter':'alpha(opacity=100)');
    $('.ex'+id).slideDown(500);
},
function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).css('opacity':'0.4','filter':'alpha(opacity=40)');
    $('.ex'+id).slideUp(500);
});
```

the hover method uses two functions. The first being the initial hover function and the second being the hover out call back function. The `.ex` element I'm guessing is generated in this fashion? `.ex0,.ex1,.ex2`. If so your function should work. If the `.ex` element is within `.case` and there are more than one `.case` this selector can be used:

```
$('.ex',this)
```

If you have a list of this elements you could use your method of retireving the id and use the `:eq()` index selector:

```
$('.ex:eq('+id+')')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead.

The events `mouseover` and `mouseout` are also triggered if you move from each child element to another in the element that has the bound event.

You can also use `hover` which is an alias for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/j5yTU/1/

```
 $("div.case img").mouseover(function () {
   ....
 }

  $("div.case img").mouseout(function () {
   ....
 }
```

Comment: basically the `div.case` element will gets taller once the `ex` div rolls down => if you have your mouse near by that area you are still hover the `div.case`